# bulkDelete function in discord.js deletes more than what it is supposed to delete

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Iam a newbie to js and i wanted to try and create a discord bot using discord.js

I used the tutorial from youtube to do this code.
This is the link of the video tutorial which helped me build this code (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INQgI-MQcj0)
.This code deletes more than what its supposed to delete, idont know what went wrong.

this is my code...

```
    module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: "Clears the certain number of messsages.",
    async execute(message, args){
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("Please enter the amount of messages that you want to clear!");
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("Please enter real number!");

        if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply("You cannnot delete more than 100 messages at a time!");
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply("You must delete at least one message");

        await message.channel.messages.fetch({Limit: args[0]}).then(messages =>{
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        });
      }
    }
```

This is the main fn

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Knight is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
    else if(command === 'hi'){
        client.commands.get('hi').execute(message, args);
    }
    else if(command === 'token'){
        client.commands.get('token').execute(message, args);
    }
    else if(command === 'hey'){
        client.commands.get('hey').execute(message, args);
    }
    else if(command === "kick_permission"){
        client.commands.get("kick_permission").execute(message, args);
    }
    else if(command === "rules"){
        client.commands.get("rules").execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
    else if(command === 'clear'){
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
    }
    
});

client.login('token');
```

This is the error it gave after accidentally deleting the whole text channel.

```
(node:5876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: You can only bulk delete messages that are under 14 days old.    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (D:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async TextChannel.bulkDelete (D:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:342:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:5876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5876) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Help me out please and Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by deletes more than its meant to?

Comment: if i type " -clear 3" it deletes more than 3 messages from the text channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo when passing the Options: `{ Limit: args[0] }` `limit` Should be lower case. So the function tries to bulk delete 100 messages not only so many messages you limited. So replace `{ Limit: args[0] }`  with `{ limit: args[0] }`.

And BTW you can filter messages which are older than 14 days (You can only delete messages which are younger than 14 days) with an argument you can pass with the function: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete (filterOld)

Comment: this is the correct answer, the spelling mistake actually makes a huge difference, it unreliably deletes messages. please mark this as the answer by clicking on the tick mark next to this answer.

Comment: Thankyou so much Xandrrr .... This fixed my problems

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are trying to delete messages that are over 14 days old (the Discord API only allows the bulkDelete function to delete messages under 14 days old). Try and purge messages that are recent. I used your code with my bot as a test and it worked fine.
Please let me know how this worked.

As well as this, the below answer mentions how you spelt `limit` with a capital L.  This is why your bot is deleting messages unreliably.